# Selenium cannot connect to chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver, seleniumbase

Here is my code. Works perfectly on local machine but in pythonanywhere I am getting this error.

**Code:**

```
from seleniumbase import Driver
    driver = Driver(uc=True, headless=True, no_sandbox=True, disable_gpu=True)
    
        try:
            driver.get('https://google.com/')
            print("Page title was '{}'".format(driver.title))
        finally:
            driver.quit()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mefor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumbase/core/browser_launcher.py", line 3478, in get_local_driver
    driver = undetected.Chrome(
  File "/home/mefor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumbase/undetected/__init__.py", line 312, in __init__
    super().__init__(options=options, service=service_)
  File "/home/mefor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/mefor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/home/mefor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/home/mefor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumbase/undetected/__init__.py", line 448, in start_session
    super().start_session(capabilities)
  File "/home/mefor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/home/mefor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/mefor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:9222
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55bb84c92e89 <unknown>
```

Before I tried directly undetected_chromedriver it was giving same error too.
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

```
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument('--disable-application-cache')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--incognito")

driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
    with driver:
        driver.get('https://google.com')
```

**This code works in pythonanywhere**

```
from sbvirtualdisplay import Display
from seleniumbase import Driver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1440, 1880))
display.start()

driver = Driver(uc=True, headless=False, incognito=True)
try:
    driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("https://google.com/", 3)
finally:
    driver.quit()

display.stop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SB()` instead of `Driver()` so that you get the built-in virtual display that you need when running on a Linux Server that has no GUI:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, xvfb=True) as sb:
    sb.driver.get("https://google.com/")
    print("Page title was '{}'".format(sb.driver.title))
```

(Otherwise you'll need to use https://github.com/mdmintz/sbVirtualDisplay)

If for some reason `xvfb=True` didn't work for you, use `headless2=True` instead. From all the Linux environments I've seen, either `xvfb=True` OR `headless2=True` does the trick when using the `SB()` format.

If you're sticking with the `Driver()` format, then know how to use `sbvirtualdisplay` correctly:

```py
from sbvirtualdisplay import Display
from seleniumbase import Driver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1440, 1880))
display.start()

driver = Driver(uc=True, headless=False, incognito=True)
try:
    driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("https://google.com/", 3)
finally:
    driver.quit()

display.stop()
```

(That overrides the default headless mode on Linux and forces your script to go through the virtual display instead.)

---

Also note that sometimes, `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:9222 from chrome not reachable` means that Chrome wasn't installed on the machine already. If that's the case, make sure that Chrome gets installed first.

Comment: Thank you so much !! with 'sbvirtualdisplay' everything is working. But I ran into one more problem because of my chrome. 
I cannot do all the operations I want due to the Chrome version in Pythonanywhere.
"Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212"

Comment: You'll have to install a newer version of Chrome separately. SeleniumBase downloads drivers, but it doesn't download web browsers.

Comment: Thanks to you sir I handled all my Linux Server problems. I am facing problems every time and I think it is the nature of the producing something. So my new problem is :

Page title was 'Sign in - Google Accounts'
No Such Element Exception
Page title was 'Sign in - Google Accounts'

normally prints should be like this ( like my local machine ) :
Page title was 'Sign in - Google Accounts'
No Such Element Exception
Page title was 'Channel dashboard - Youtube Studio'

When I want to go to the youtube studio I cannot.

Comment: Your comment looks like a separate question to be asked. If the solution above answers your original question, then you should mark the above solution as the answer, and then ask your new question separately. You’ll need to provide enough code in your question to make it answerable.

Comment: Your from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, xvfb=True) as sb:
    sb.driver.get("https://google.com/")
    print("Page title was '{}'".format(sb.driver.title))

solution helped me a lot thanks !